# fail2ban: whitelist IPv6 address

Tags: ipv6, fail2ban, whitelist

I need to whitelist an ipv6 address in fail2ban, however when I just add them to the ignoreip statement in my jail.conf they get blocked anyways.
This is what I have in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`

```
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 192.168.100.0/24 , 2a02:2020:2020::1,
```

Any one knows how to white list an IPv6 addess in fail2ban?

Answer (score 9):

[ignoreip is space delimited](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist). Delete the comma.

Confirm the address is correct by cross referencing all the IPs on the host to allow, with the logs of the service in question.

Consider allowing nets of yours rather than single IPs for v6 as well. For example, `2a02:2020:2020::1/64`.